# How to stop Triggering the alarm for the past days/time

Tags: alarm

If I need to set the alarm for tuesday and thursday, but i set the alarm on wednesday then how to avoid the instant trigger for past Tuesday but not for the coming Tuesday? Any help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, you haven't provided any relevant, testable code in this question and hence we have to figure out by coding the entire game ourselves. As a result, your question may be too broad.It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code only helps to get the alarm weekly(Once a week)

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dayOfWeek);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(time[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(time[1]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY *7,pendingIntent);
```

But If i need to get the alarm on tuesday but i set th alarm on wednesday then it automatically trigger the alarm for the past tuesday which i don't need. I need the alarm only fron next tuesday.

I an new in android, I would be helful if any one can help me